# How to make Excel cell show specific value based on time range?

Tags: excel

Currently trying an experiment with Excel where a cell will either show me A or B depending on the system time.

A when time 7 am - 6 pm, and the remainder will be B.

My plan is for the cell to change value to B when it reaches 6 pm without the need to restart the Excel. I'm currently using the formula

```
=IF(AND(TIME(7,0,0),TIME(18,0,0)),"A","B")
```

but all I'm getting is A only. Even when I change the system time to over 6 pm, its still A. Is there anywhere the formula needs improving? Or do I need to use VBA to do this?

Comment: with just excel formula, even for the answer below, you will have to restart the excel or make change in any cell for the excel to calculate `NOW()`. You may try google'ing for vba solution

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Time is in `Cell A1` , use this formula

```
=IF(AND(A1>TIME(7,0,0),A1<TIME(18,0,0)),"A","B")
```

See image for reference

[image]

**EDIT :** As per comment

---

> my plan is to get the time directly from the computer's built in clock. is that possible

To get current system time you can use any of the following formula.

`=NOW()-TODAY()`

`=TIME(HOUR(NOW()),MINUTE(NOW()),SECOND(NOW()))`

Thus, formula you are looking for will be

```
=IF(AND(NOW()-TODAY()>TIME(7,0,0),NOW()-TODAY()<TIME(18,0,0)),"A","B")
```

Comment: what if I don't have the time written in excel? my plan is to get the time directly from the computer's built in clock. is that possible?

Comment: @hjh93 - Did this help?